# Regex with conditional html tag

Tags: c#, regex

I need to write a Regex that captures whats inside a specific HTML tag:

```
<span class="sentences">CAPTURE HERE</span>
```

So I wrote, in C#:

```
<span class=\"sentence\">((.|\\\\s)*?)</span>
```

The problem I'm having and I'm not sure how to solve it, is that there is another span class inside that span that also ends with </span> and therefore is ending the capture on the wrong closing tag. How do I write a condition in a Regex that checks if there is another span class that is not "sentences" and if it does, that the capture should end on the next </span>?

The input string on the Regex.

```
<span class="sentence">O que a história da escravidão tem a dizer sobre <span class="CharOverride-15">experiências religiosas</span>?</span><span class="sentence"> Só silêncios,</span>
```

What I want to ideally capture:

```
O que a história da escravidão tem a dizer sobre <span class="CharOverride-15">experiências religiosas</span>? Só silêncios,
```

Comment: There are libraries that handle this for you [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

Comment: "Asking for HTML, JSON, etc. regexes tends to be met with negative reactions. If there is a parser for it, use that instead." - From the regex tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Regex to parse html. Use a real html parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlstring);
var span = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='sentence']");
var text = span.InnerText;
var html = span.InnerHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

As an exercise (html parsing library is preferred), here is a regex that can parse with or without a nested tag:

```
<([^>]+)(?:\s+[^>]*)?>[^<>]*?(?:<([^>]+)(?:\s+[^>]*)?>)?(?<capture>[^<>]+)(?:<\/\2>)?[^<>]*?<\/\1>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW1ruV/2)